# XML Schema: how to ensure a "fixed" element to be not empty?

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation, string

I have the following code:

```
<xs:element name="Lang" fixed="de-CH" nillable="false">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:language">
      <xs:minLength value="5"/>
      <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

I would like to ensure that the element `Lang` is not empty. If I delete `fixed` attribute, the validation for non-emptiness works. Is it a way to do it without removing `fixed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve both fixedness and non-emptyness using `xs:pattern` restriction:

```
<xs:element name="Lang">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:language">
      <xs:minLength value="5"/>
      <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
      <xs:pattern value="de-CH"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
<xs:element name="Lang">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:language">
       <xs:enumeration value="de-CH" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```